# React TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of null

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to fill 2nd dropdown based on selection from 1st dropdown in React.Js. My code is below. When i choose option i am getting this error: " Cannot read property 'target' of null"
By the way am using Ant-design's Select. When I use ordinary select option it works without error. Why this error happen?

```
   state={
    periodTypes: [
        { name: 'MONTH', period: ['period1-1', 'period1-2', 'period1-3'] },
        { name: 'QUARTER', period: ['1', '2', '3', '4'] },
        { name: 'HALF_YEAR', period: ['1', '2'] },
        { name: 'YEAR', period: ['2019', '2020'] }
    ],
    selectedPeriodType: 'YEAR'
   }
handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e)
    this.setState({ selectedPeriodType: e.target.value })
};
render() {
    let periodtype = this.state.periodTypes.filter(periodtype => {
        return periodtype.name === this.state.selectedPeriodType
    })
    return (

 <div className="w-24 mr-md-3 mb-4">
  <Select className=" height-53  w-100" name="" id="" placeholder="Dövrün tipi"  value= 
  {this.state.selectedPeriodType} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}> {                                        
  this.state.periodTypes.map((periodtype, i) => {
   return <Option>{periodtype.name}</Option>   }) }
  </Select>
 </div>

 <div className="w-24 mr-md-3 mb-4">
   <Select className=" height-53  w-100" name="" id="" placeholder="Dövr">
   {periodtype[0].period.map((period, i) => {
    return <Option>{period}</Option>
     })}
   </Select>
      </div>
   )
```

Comment: What did you get when you `console.log(e)` ?

Comment: Null, but when i replace <Select> with <select>, It works properly. But I want to use Ant-Design's Select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `e.target.value` you can access value directly in `antd` select

```
function handleChange(value) {
  console.log(`selected ${value}`);
}
```

Sample code - https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd485-forked-5q451